# launch SAS code through VBA modules and licence needed

Tags: vba, excel, sas, connection

I am trying to launch the following SAS code through VBA. But an

> error 429 ActiveX can't create the object

is showing.
Does someone know which licenses/Modules/required_drivers are needed for SAS or Excel? 
I am using SAS Enterprise Guide 6.1 and Microsoft Office 15.
The same code worked before on the other PC containing all SAS licenses for SAS 9.3 and Microsoft Office 16.

```
    Dim OleSAS As Object
    Set OleSAS = CreateObject("SAS.Application")
    OleSAS.Visible = True
    OleSAS.Wait = True
    OleSAS.Submit("SAScode")
    OleSAS.Quit
    Set OleSAS = Nothing
```

Comment: You're trying to launch a local SAS.EXE?  Or when you say you use enterprise guide, you're actually submitting code to a server and don't have local SAS?

Comment: "ActiveX can't create object" usually means the ProgID you've given `CreateObject` either doesn't exist in the Windows Registry, or the type library otherwise isn't registered for late-binding, or the bitness isn't compatible (e.g. trying to use a 64-bit library from a 32-bit process). Given that same code worked on another machine, I'd first confirm the bitness of the host application (Excel) is the same on both machines, then verify the library registration.

Comment: @Joe Yes I want to submit my SAS code to SAS.exe. SAS is locally installed.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thank you very much, I will check it out

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to call SAS from VBA is via the StoredProcess server.  This approach also nicely separates the SAS code from VBA logic.  An explanation can be found [here](https://www.rawsas.com/2016/11/sas-as-a-service-an-easy-way-to-get-sas-into-excel-power-bi-and-000s-of-other-tools-languages/), which essentially involves:

- Registering your SAS code as a Stored Process with streaming output
- Setting up a web query in excel, with relevant parameters in the url
- Calling the `refresh` event on the `QueryTables` object

Another nice thing about this approach is that you don't need the addin, or a local instance of SAS.  However you do need SSO.